# Loader image for rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi In my rails application on one page I have links which links to another page which will call some APIs, so that page loads slowly. I need some indication till the page renders, how to accomplish this? I have searched most of them says solution for AJAX request but here its not a ajax request.....

Answer (score 0):

Add in your **application.js**

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
  showloader()
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){ 
  hideloader()
});


function showloader(){
 $(".main-loader").show()
}

function hideloader(){
 $(".main-loader").hide()
}
```

Add in your application.html.erb

```
    <div class="main-loader" style="display: none;">
      <div class="loader-div"> <%= image_tag "loader.gif" %> </div>
    </div>
```

And Also Add loader image in your assets images folder